# How to use javaScript variable, inside html checkbox value parameter?

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

In my file I have javaScript variable name 'testJava'

```
<script>
var testJava = 'script Test';
</script>
```

At the bottom of the page I have a checkbox. **I need to add 'testJava' variable to the value of the checkbox**.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="website[]" value= "I_WANT_TO_ADD_IT_HERE" />My Test<br />
```

`value = "<script>document.write(testJava);</script>"` doesn't work

Can anyone please tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script>
var testJava = 'script Test';
document.getElementById('checkbox_ID').value = testJava;
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add an `id` tag to your `<input>` element to identify it:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="website[]" id="thecheckbox" />
```

Using jQuery, it's quite easy to change the value:

```
$('#thecheckbox').val(testJava);
```

To include jQuery, e.g. use the following script tag:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: I wanted to post an alternative solution. Now I've included instructions to include jQuery in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var checkBox = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
checkBox.value = testJava;
```

Note: this must be done within a `window.onload` event or in a script positioned after the checkbox HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly do what you're asking, so just set the value after the fact:

```
<input type=checkbox id=cb1 ...> My Test
<script>
  document.getElementById('cb1').value = testJava;
</script>
```

Also, Java and JavaScript are not the same thing.

Make sure the `<script>` is after the `<input>`, or else that it's in a "load" or "ready" event handler.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="website[]" id="check_box" value= "I_WANT_TO_ADD_IT_HERE" />My Test<br />
```

in your script, after the dom ready,

```
document.getElementById("check_box").value("testJava");
```